# How make an Ember computed property update when any item in an array is changed?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Let's say I have the following data:

```
[
  { id: "54101", name: "A\1" },
  { id: "cbbb4", name: "A\2" },
  { id: "b4e37", name: "B\1" },
  { id: "ff099", name: "B\2" },
  { id: "8715f", name: "B\3" },
  { id: "1f414", name: "C\1\a" },
  { id: "77ba6", name: "C\1\b" }
]
```

Loaded via a promise in my route.

I would like to have a property, called `rootNode` that would have this structure:
*(I already have code to do this with POJOs, so the logic required to convert this object can be ignored)*

```
{
  name: null,
  value: null,
  children: [
    {
      name: "A",
      value: null,
      children: [
        { name: "1", value: /* object above */, children: [] },
        { name: "2", value: /* object above */, children: [] }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      value: null,
      children: [
        { name: "1", value: /* object above */, children: [] },
        { name: "2", value: /* object above */, children: [] },
        { name: "3", value: /* object above */, children: [] }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "C",
      value: null,
      children: [
        {
          name: "1",
          value: null,
          children: [
            { name: "a", value: /* object above */, children: [] },
            { name: "b", value: /* object above */, children: [] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Ember, is it possible to create a computed property that will update this tree whenever any of the names changes, or when items are added or removed?

I've been using Ember for all of 18 hours now, and I'm a bit lost.  I already had this implemented using Angular's `$watch` functionality, but I had to move off of Angular due to limitations in other areas.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I completely understand how one moves from the original data to the updated data, it's a little difficult to give a correct answer not knowing exactly what's going on.  Would you be able to change it to either a generic transformation, or explain how one goes from a -> b

Comment: I just need ember to update.  I have the code to perform the transformation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `@each`:

```
Ember.computed('myArrayProp.@each.somePropToObserve', function() {
  /* your code here */
})
```